# How to handle on change for an input in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component UserInput and its used in App component(class based.) Now i am not able to render the onChange event in my html

```
import React from 'react';


const userInput =(props) =>{
    return(
        <input  onChange={props.changed} />
    );
};

export default userInput;
```

My app component looks like this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import UserInput from './UserInput/UserInput';
import UserOutput from './UserOutput/UserOutput';

class App extends Component{
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
        this.state = { userName: "dssdf" };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

    }
    const handleChange = (event) =>{
            this.setState({
                userName: event.target.value
            })
        }

    render(){

        return(
            <div >
                <UserInput changed={this.handleChange} />
                <UserOutput userName={this.state.userName} />

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

Any help is appriciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please show us the code in the other two components.

Comment: First of all, components in react have to be in capital letters (if not, JSX thinks they're HTML tags), it should be ``const UserInput`` and ``export default UserInput``

Comment: this is not a place for people to code for you. It seems like you haven't grasped a basic understanding of react which can be gotten from the docs.

Comment: Please go with documentation

Answer (score 1):

pass the state as value to `<input />`

```
import React from 'react';


const userInput =(props) =>{
    return(
        <input value={props.value} onChange={props.changed} />
    );
};

export default userInput;

class App extends Component{
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
        this.state = { userName: "dssdf" };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

    }
    const handleChange = (event) =>{
            this.setState({
                userName: event.target.value
            })
        }

    render(){

        return(
            <div >
                <UserInput value={this.state.userName} changed={this.handleChange} />
                <UserOutput userName={this.state.userName} />

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```